# Why can't I pass a string as the data argument to Blaze.renderWithData()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm creating a Blaze View with the following call:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.my_template, myobj._id, html.node());
```

`my_template` looks like this:

```
<template name="my_template">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=whichTemplate data=sdata}}
</template>
```

The sdata helper looks like this:

```
sdata: function() {
  return Doodads.findOne({_id: this});
}
```

Which fails with the following error:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: selKey.substr is not a function

If I do `console.log(this)` within that helper, I get:

```
String {0: "N", 1: "7", 2: "j", 3: "o", 4: "y", 5: "g", 6: "w", 7: "P", 8: "g", 9: "e", 10: "s", 11: "R", 12: "f", 13: "w", 14: "q", 15: "o", 16: "7", length: 17, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "N7joygwPgesRfwqo7"}
```

To correct the problem, I can change the `findOne()` line to:

```
  return Doodads.findOne({_id: ""+this});
```

Which works as expected.

---

I am posting this question to help myself (and others) understand what is going on here.

Mainly I want to know:

- Why is there difference between using a `String{...}` object and a regular string for this call (i.e, why doesn't the selector key object have a `substr()` method when I'm using a different/weird selector value)?
- Why does the `_id` property show up as this weird `String{...}` object as the template data `this` when the `_id` property is usually just a string?  Or is it not usually and I've just never noticed?

I've solved the problem with the `""+this` hack, but is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: You did not mention what is `myobj`. Moreover, a string object is not a string primitive and your error comes from minimongo, not Blaze. A minimal reproduction code would be helpful.

Comment: @MasterAM `myobj` is being passed into my `addedAt` callback for `Doodads.find({}).observe(...)`, with sig `function(myobj, atIndex, before)`.  Before being passed into `renderWithData()`, the _id field is a primitive string.  I will try to get a minimal case working and edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## what is wrong?

According to the [Blaze API docs](http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-renderWithData), the signature is:

`Blaze.renderWithData(templateOrView, data, parentNode, [nextNode], [parentView])`

> **data** *Object or Function*
>
> The data context to use, or a function returning a data context. If a function is provided, it will be reactively re-run.

The data context, in your case, should be an object which includes a `whichTemplate` property and some `id` that you can use in your helper.

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.my_template, {
  _id: myId, 
  whichTemplate: someTemplateName
}, someNode);
```

or, instead of a data object, pass a function that will be reactively re-run.

With this setup, your helper code should be something like:

```
sdata: function() {
  return Doodads.findOne(this._id);
}
```

## source of the error you were seeing

If you are interested in the cause of the error you were getting, here's what is going on:

In blaze, the countext is bound to the template helper's `this` reference using `Function.protptype.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])` (in [this line](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/blob/master/packages/blaze/lookup.js#L28)).

According to the EcmaScript standard, if `thisArg` is a primitive, it will be boxed.

> **thisArg**
>
> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, **and primitive values will be boxed**.
>
> (source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

This causes a `String` object, which does not have a `substr` method, be transferred to the `MiniMongo.Collection`'s `find()` method, which [fails here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/abd574f38008b45f5e2a6bc322b10bcdde44763a/packages/minimongo/helpers.js#L28).

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is created from some other source than a Meteor subscription, it could be that your _id is a MongoDB ObjectId, which is not a string.

Have a look in the Mongo shell, if you do a .findOne on the `myobj` object and it shows up looking something like

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57cd946429bca10300f0fd55")
```

Comment: In both the mongo shell and if I do a `console.log(myobj._id)` right before the `renderWithData(...)` call it is showing up as a string primitive.  Also, if it were a MongoDB ObjectId, shouldn't it work?

Comment: `ObjectId('foo') != 'foo'`, but `ObjectId('foo').toString() == 'foo'`

That's why I thought it could be the issue. In the browser console they look like strings, this has fooled me before. But if they are strings in the MongoDB console that is not the problem.